# Marker is not being displayed on map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

http://pastebin.com/hGGGUL3a

Is there any idea why this code doesn't show the marker?  Reason i have the marker code in a separate function is due to future changes where the button will obtain new data from a database thus update.

Many Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't work at all, doesn't show the map. Reason is line 23:

```
        });
```

Once you get there, the line:

```
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: google.maps.LatLng(52.907135, -1.093140),
            map: map
        });
```

should be:

```
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.907135, -1.093140),
            map: map
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it would be a simple mistake like that just couldn't find it.... was looking for around 4 hours....